# OpenCV3.0 and Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I need to use OpenCV with Qt creator, and need some help with OpenCV.

My problem occurs when I run any example or .exe made with OpenCV, after I install OpenCV with CMake (and checking WITH_QT in the process).

For example with the examples included in the installation, when I try to open one I get the following error:

http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/1413994743487541.png

That says: Procedure entry point not found in the dynamic links library

My S.O. is Windows 8.1, 64 bits

I have tried to reinstall Qt and install differents versions, but the error is the same ever.

But, if I install OpenCV with CMake and don´t check WITH_QT, the examples works perfectly.

I dont know what else can I do!
Thanks!

Comment: Put the DLL in the folder with the exe.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the error remains, I have added the libraries to environment system path  and I paste that .dll into my samples folder, but the error is the same

Comment: Have you tried a native build?  You can build both Qt and OpenCV+Qt with CMake and Visual Studio.

Comment: i've already tried that, and still crash

Comment: Which version of Qt? 32bit or 64bit? Whats the compiler used to build Qt? Do you use the same compiler when building OpenCV?